# Does array query "field." without position index is valid?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm confused if my query for arrays is valid or is some kind of hack or bug.

I try to find documents

```
db.test.find({field.: {"$exists": true}})
```

As you can see I have `field.` without index position.
It does what I think it should do, but there is nothing about it in docs.

If this is a bug, then my query will not work after fixing mongo.

I'm using version `3.2`

Thanks!

Comment: Humm I don't know if I get it. Do you want to know if field is a non-empty array?

Comment: @andresk I would like to find documents where given field is array (empty or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the only way to find out is to dive in the [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/231de89b7c8e84b7b6cf638008b483ecab6ba1b6/src/mongo/db/bson/dotted_path_support.cpp#L58-L125).

As you can see, this is the expected result. What happen here is that MongoDB does not do anything with the dot in field's name here. How?

When you use the dot notation to access a field, what MongoDB does is *split* the string using the dot as delimiter. From there and depending of the value of two sub-string it decides what to do. here the statement [`L88-L105`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/231de89b7c8e84b7b6cf638008b483ecab6ba1b6/src/mongo/db/bson/dotted_path_support.cpp#L88-L105) is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The code you mentioned is not giving any error, but you should not use it is not a mongodb functionality and may not work in future versions.

And as I checked this is working only with arrays, if you try with a normal field it will not give you record even if it exists and **for arrays it is satisfying the condition even if array is empty**.

So if you want to check array is empty or not use

```
db.test.find({"field.1": {"$exists": true}})
```

Comment: thx for your answer.

What I wanted to achieve was to find all documents where given field is array (empty or not). Your snippet returns me only documents witch have at least do elements.

So, this also won't satisfy me
`db.test.find({"field.0": {"$exists": true}}) `

Comment: Plz upvote or mark correct if you find answer helpful